# Python: Convert list to dict keys for multidimensional dict with exception handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

I have a collection of multidimensional dictionaries that looks as follows

```
dict1 = {'key21':{'key31': {'key41':val41}, 'key32':{'key42':val42}}}
```

Apriori, I dont know the dimensions of the dictionary. I have a huge collection of possible keys and each dictionary might or might not contain the keys. Even if present, the keys may not have to be in the same order.

If I create a list of possible key values from the collection, say

```
list1 = ['key21', 'key32', 'key42']
```

How can I pass the list as key so that I can get the value of `dict1['key21']['key32']['key42']` with exception handling similar to [get](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) command

Comment: A good first start would be by writing some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the dictionary iteratively, like this:

```
dict1 = {'key21':{'key31': {'key41':41}, 'key32':{'key42':42}}}
list1 = ['key21', 'key32', 'key42']
#list1 = ['key21', 'key32', 'key42', 'bad-key'] # Test bad key
item = dict1
try:
    for key in list1:
            item = item[key]
except (KeyError, TypeError):
    print None
else:
    print item
```

`KeyError` handles the case where the key doesn't exist.
`TypeError` handles the case where the item is not a dictionary, and hence, further lookup cannot be done. This is an interesting case that's easy to miss (I did the first time).

Comment: Why not just `item = dict1[list1[0]][list1[1]][list1[2]]` inside a `try`?

Comment: According to the OP; "Apriori, I neither know the dimensions of the dictionary nor the key-values".

Comment: It works fine if the depth of the key is same as that of dictionary. You need to add an except for `TypeError` when the keylist length is longer than the dimensionality of the dict

Comment: Maybe he gets it from the user, or even from a file.

Comment: Then the source of the keys somehow "knows"?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise. I have a huge collection of possible key values to try on the dictionary and each individual dictionary might or might not have all the keys, and if present might not have to be in the same order.